# Mailer class. Send method

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4, mailer

I have a problem with the send method of mailer class:

```
public function deliver()
{
         $self = $this;
         return \Mail::send($this->body, $this->data, function($message) use($self)
    {
        $message->to($self->email, $self->to)->subject($self->subject);    
    });
}
```

I retrieve $this->body from a form.
And i want to sent it as TEXT. just plain text.
But somehow i am forced to send VIEW.
So if in the body field i write the name of a view, like 'master', the mail is sent with master view as content.
If i write plain text, the app break and i get an error that the text inserted is not a view.

How can i do to send only text?

Thank you!

Comment: try creating a blank view and use that view :p

Comment: in this way i send a blank view :)
How can now assign what to pass as body of the mail?

Comment: In the 'blank.blade.php' file, use `{{ $content }}` - pass the content variable in $this->data.

Comment: How can i pass $content in $this->data ?
How can use that variable if is only in that view, and there is not any route for that?

Comment: Resolved! Was as easy as pass it in the data array:  
$this->data['content'] = $this->body;
Thank you Rob!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you send it without a view:

```
Mail::send([], [], function($message) {

        $message->setBody('your full text body, or html...');

        $message->to('my@email.com');

        $message->subject('my subject');

    });
```